# How to drop all rows below string match dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, drop

I have a dataframe and I interested only the data above string text = "purchase" by session.
[input dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ars8p.png)

| session | Date | action | flag_purchase |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T001 | 01-01-2021 00.01 | click | 1 |
| T001 | 01-01-2021 00.15 | play | 1 |
| T001 | 01-01-2021 02.15 | pause | 1 |
| T001 | 01-01-2021 03.15 | play | 1 |
| T001 | 01-01-2021 04.15 | purchase | 1 |
| T001 | 02-01-2021 10.15 | play | 1 |
| T001 | 02-01-2021 12.00 | pause | 1 |
| T001 | 02-01-2021 13.15 | play | 1 |
| T002 | 01-01-2021 00.01 | play | 0 |
| T002 | 03-01-2021 00.15 | play | 0 |
| T002 | 03-01-2021 02.15 | pause | 0 |
| T002 | 03-01-2021 03.15 | play | 0 |

I want to drop all rows below action = "purchase", If all actions in session doesn’t have text match the session will keep all rows, so the output that I want looks like:

[final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hm79x.png)

| session | Date | action | flag_purchase |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T001 | 01-01-2021 00.01 | click | 1 |
| T001 | 01-01-2021 00.15 | play | 1 |
| T001 | 01-01-2021 02.15 | pause | 1 |
| T001 | 01-01-2021 03.15 | play | 1 |
| T001 | 01-01-2021 04.15 | purchase | 1 |
| T002 | 01-01-2021 00.01 | play | 0 |
| T002 | 03-01-2021 00.15 | play | 0 |
| T002 | 03-01-2021 02.15 | pause | 0 |
| T002 | 03-01-2021 03.15 | play | 0 |

Comment: In your expected output there's rows below `purchase` as well?

Comment: @CutePoison I think it's just the entries below purchase for that session ID.  In the expected output, the rows below purchase are a different session ID.

Comment: Aaah.. makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then you can do the following:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"id":[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3],
"action":["pause","play","purchase","purchase","play","purchase","pause","play","play","pause"]})

print(df)

#   id  action
# 0  1  pause
# 1  1  play
# 2  1  purchase
# 3  1  purchase
# 4  2  play
# 5  2  purchase
# 6  2  pause
# 7  2  play
# 8  3  play
# 9  3  pause


def get_idx(row):
    """
    Gets the first index of where "purchase" occurs, then 
    return the rows untill and incl that index
    """

    idx = np.argwhere(row.values=="purchase") #get index
    if idx.size>0: #check if it exists
        idx = idx[0][0]+1
        return row[:idx] #return the rows
    return row #else, return the original rows

df_clean = df.groupby("id")["action"].apply(get_idx).reset_index(drop=False,level=0)

#    id action
# 0  1  pause
# 1  1  play
# 2  1  purchase
# 4  2  play
# 5  2  purchase
# 8  3  play
# 9  3  pause
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
to_remove = lambda x: ~x.shift().eq('purchase').cumsum().astype(bool)
out = df[df.groupby('session')['action'].apply(to_remove)]
print(out)

# Output
   session              Date    action  flag_purchase
0     T001  01-01-2021 00.01     click              1
1     T001  01-01-2021 00.15      play              1
2     T001  01-01-2021 02.15     pause              1
3     T001  01-01-2021 03.15      play              1
4     T001  01-01-2021 04.15  purchase              1
8     T002  01-01-2021 00.01      play              0
9     T002  03-01-2021 00.15      play              0
10    T002  03-01-2021 02.15     pause              0
11    T002  03-01-2021 03.15      play              0
```

Comment: It's very close but I don't want to drop action = purchase